# Why can't I access a port on my AWS instance, even though I have security group inbound rules that allow it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS so this is probably a "doh!" question.

I set up a CentOS 7 instance and assigned a elastic IP. I created a security group and created a custom TCP inbound rule that allows TCP traffic on port 8000 anywhere (0.0.0.0/0), an HTTP rule for port 80  also from 0.0.0.0/0, and SSH/port 22 rule from my laptop IP, and assigned the security group to my instance. **iptables/6, firewalld, nor SELinux services are NOT running on the box.**

I CAN SSH to the box with the elastic IP. I CAN access http://my_elastic_ip, but I can NOT access http://my_elastic_ip:8000/some.html

netstat shows the 8000 port in listening state, on all addresses.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is whatever process is listening on port 8000 listening for 0.0.0.0:8000 or just 127.0.0.1:8000?  What error do you actually get when you try to connect?

Comment: What are you running on port 8000? Not every server responds to http requests.

Comment: Try running this command on the instance "sudo nmap -T Aggressive -A -v 127.0.0.1 -p 1-65000" and then check if it works

Comment: @KarenB, process is listening on ALL addresses on 8000, per netstat. Deepak, it's a 3rd party application we're testing with our product. errer2007s, where do I run the nmap command?

Comment: At the command line of the instance

Comment: @error2007s: Thanks, I followed your suggestion and see this for port 8000 - "Discovered open port 8000/tcp on 127.0.0.1". I see this when I do a netstat -anp | grep 8000 "tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      3791/java"

Comment: So your port is open but your application is not listening on that port then

Comment: @error2007s: I see this when I start the application "2016-07-09 15:46:09.954:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:Thread-2: Started ServerConnector@1768ff79{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8000}" AAMOF, I see this while the application is running, and I run nmap "***Unhandled http request /
404:/"

Comment: Are you using a VPC you set up or has someone else set it up?  Have you checked the network ACLs?

Comment: Yes we have a VPC that someone else set up. Elastic IP is 52.x and VPC in 10.x. How do I check network ACLs?

Comment: I've been reading more on network ACLs, and that can very well be it - the rules in my VPCs may be blocking (not allowing) traffic on port 8000.

Comment: Well the network ACLs of the VPC my subnet belongs to allows all traffic, so that's not it.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out, these ports were blocked by my company's firewall. Enabling them resolved this issue.